# How can I prevent my custom directive from getting compiled/executed every time I use $route.reload()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have built a custom directive to enable arrow key navigation in a dropdown.

This is my HTML code

```
<div ng-click="dropdownShow = !dropdownShow" id="dropdownToggle" arrow-navigation>
    {{currentlySelectedItem}}
</div>

<div ng-show="dropdownShow">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list" id="row_{{$index}}" ng-click="getItemInfo($index)">
        <span>{{item}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JS code

```
app.directive('arrowNavigation', ['$document', function($document){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $document.bind('keydown',function(e){
                // check if dropdown open
                if(scope.dropdownShow){
                    // if down arrow key pressed
                    if(e.keyCode === 40){
                        console.log("down arrow key pressed");
                        // When the dropdown is first opened, the focus will be on the dropdownToggle. 
                        // In this case, I'm moving the focus to the first item on the list.
                        if(document.activeElement.id === "dropdownToggle"){
                            document.getElementById('row_0').focus();
                        }
                        else{
                            let currentFocused = document.activeElement.id;
                            // currentFocused = row_ + $index
                            let index = currentFocused.substring(4);
                            // index = $index of currently focused item
                            console.log(index);
                            index++;
                            // check if the currently focused item is the last item on the list
                            // In this case, move the focus back to the first item on the list
                            if(index >= scope.list.length){
                                document.getElementById('row_0').focus();
                            }
                            else{
                                document.getElementById('row_' + index).focus();
                            }
                        }
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                // there's similar code for up arrow key press. I have decided to skip it for the sake of simplicity.
                }
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

The first time I use the dropdown, everything works perfectly. 
But when I select any item from the dropdown, the resulting ng-click function has a `$route.reload` inside it. This causes my ng-view to get reloaded. That's when the problem starts. After the first reload, when I try to use the dropdown, it gets executed twice for every single arrow click. So if the first list item is focused, and I press the down arrow key, instead of moving the focus to the second item, it moves the focus to the third item. Upon every subsequent `$route.reload()`, the number of executions increases by one.

I'm guessing that this is happening cause everytime the route gets reloaded, the directive is being re-rendered, causing multiple copies of the same directive, all of which then get executed on the arrow click.

Is there any way to prevent this re-rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the event listener when scope is destroyed

```
// inside link
scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    $document.unbind('keydown')
});
```

Note that `angular.element` bind and unbind are deprecated so am assuming you may be using a fairly old version. Most recent versions use `on()` and `off()`